# how to adjust view according to their with in android

Tags: line

I want to take a container, in which I want to add some view like recycler view and list view, but in recycler view, the view gets recycle, But what I want is that I want to adjust the view in line like if view width is small, then more view can be put in a single line and if view width is big then less view will come. it will be adjusted by view width. Please help me with how can I achieve this functionality in android.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use constraint layout, create constraints views using "match_constraints","match_parent","wrap_content" for size.
- Try using scalable sizes for margins and let Android scale it accordingly.

> res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml

> res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml